# send another data with formData using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I've tried using append to my formData, it did not send anything to db including the content of the file.

here is my code:-

```
$('#upload_csv').on("submit", function(e){  
          var data = new FormData(this);
         data.append('test_filename', file);

           });

            $.ajax({  
                 url:"uploadfileprocess",  
                 method:"POST",  
                 data:{data,data },  
                 contentType:false,           
                 cache:false,         
                 processData:false,      
                 success: function(data){ 
                        alert(data);
                      if(data=='Error1')  
                      {  
                           alert("Invalid File");  
                      }  
                      else if(data == "Error2")  
                      {  
                           alert("Please Select File");  
                      }  
                      else  
                      {  
                           $('#importfiletodb').html(data);  
                      }  
                 }  
            })
```

all the content and the file name should be able to save together when user click submit.

but now, only content of the file submitted to db.

how to make the file name submitted together with the content?

p/s: this is my first time using ajax to upload file.

Answer (score 0):

just replace your ajax callback with this

```
$.ajax({  
         url:"uploadfileprocess",  
         method:"POST",  
         data:{ data : data} ,  
         contentType:false,           
         cache:false,         
         processData:false,      
         success: function(data){  
              if(data=='Error1')  
              {  
                   alert("Invalid File");  
              }  
              else if(data == "Error2")  
              {  
                   alert("Please Select File");  
              }  
              else  
              {  
                   $('#importfiletodb').html(data);  
              }  
         }  
    })
```

Comment: its not working, i've replaced the callback as you do, but same thing happened:- no content and file name entered.

Comment: i've tried to alert the data back to check whether it send the value in to ajax, but failed. no data received in ajax, why?